# Contributing to someone elses remote repository

Tags: git, github

I have created a remote repository on GitHub that I push my local repository to. I am working with someone else, and they have pulled my remote repository, edited/added to it now they are trying to push a branch to the repository. The issue is, the push creates a new branch "master", but it is identical to my last push.

How can he push and merge his commits to my github repository?

Comment: What does he see if he runs `git status` ?

Comment: Can you provide the output of his `git push`?

Comment: `on branch comments` "nothing added to commit..." (since he has already committed)

Comment: `* [new branch] master -> master` when he `git pushes`

Comment: Looks like he is checked out on branch `comments`, which I assume is a local branch that he created. If he executes `git push origin comments`, does that result in branch `comments` being created in the remote repo?

Comment: `comments` is his local repo. When he pushed `git push URL origin comments` it returned `error: src refspec origin does not match any` then `error: failed to push some refs to 'url'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this was a question about how a collaborator should get access to a repo hosted on GitHub. In this case, the person who originated the repo did so by executing `git init` and then (I assume) creating the repo on GitHub, adding the GitHub repo as a remote to his local repo, then pushing his commits from the local repo to the GitHub repo.

His collaborator tried to follow a similar set of steps - create an empty dir, execute `git init` followed by `git pull https://github.com/owner/repo.git`. This resulted in having a remote named `repo` configured for pull only. He should have done `git clone https://github.com/owner/repo.git` in the parent dir, which would have set up the GitHub remote under the name of `origin`, which is the usual way of doing things.

Original answer:

`git push` with no other arguments only pushes "matching" branches - those local branches that are set up to track remote branches.

It looks like your friend has created branch `comments` locally. It's not tracking a remote branch, because there is no matching remote branch yet. To push that branch to the remote (which I assume is your origin remote), he'll need to execute this:

`git push origin comments`

That will create branch `comments` in the remote repo named `origin`. Then you can fetch from the remote and merge his commits to another branch.

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html

`origin` is the default remote name, but it could be named something else. You can see the remote configuration with

`git remote -v`

Comment: What arguments does he need to add to `git push origin comments` to create the branch in the remote repo. Just entering `git push origin comments` from his local repository just returns: `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository. Fatal: could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: I assume he cloned his local repo from the GitHub repo, and has the github repo set up as his origin remote, but maybe that's not the case. Can you show me the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: output: `oc-theme https://github.com/username/oc-theme (fetch)` and `oc-theme https://github.com/username/oc-theme (push) origin`

Comment: My repo is `https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/oc-theme`, don't know if that is important.

Comment: OK, so the remote is named `oc-theme` instead of `origin`. It's set up for fetch, but not push. Try `git push oc-theme comments`. If that fails, try `git remote add push oc-theme https://github.com/username/oc-theme.git` and then try `git push oc-theme comments` again.

Comment: push doesn't show on the `<options>` list, it shows: `-f fetch --tags -t, --track <branch> -m, --master <branch> --mirror[=<push|fetch>]` should we try one of those?

Comment: Just add the remote as origin
`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/oc-theme.git` and `git push origin comments` should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41910/discussion-between-chris-and-jscott)